# sql- not null with default, check constraint

Tags: sql, db2

I have created a table and I'm asked to add a constraint to a column called no_semesters. the condition is that the no has to be >= 0 and it should be not null with default, and the default value is 6. When I run this statement:

```
INSERT INTO PREMIERD08/PGM (PGM_ID, PGM_NAME) 
VALUES('CPD', 'COMPUTER   PROGRAMMING')
```

I get an error message saying column - no_semesters cant be null. why wont it set to the default value which is 6?

this was the statement -

```
CREATE TABLE PREMIERD08/PGM (
    PGM_ID CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PGM_NAME CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    NO_SEMESTERS NUMERIC ( 1) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 6,
    CONSTRAINT PGM_PGM_NAME_UK UNIQUE (PGM_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT PGM_PGM_ID_CK CHECK (PGM_ID IN ('CPA', 'CPD') ), 
    CONSTRAINT PGM_PGM_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PGM_ID), CONSTRAINT PGM_NO_SEMESTERS_CK CHECK (NO_SEMESTERS >= 0)
)
```

Comment: Did you run the statement to alter the column? Something like `ALTER TABLE PGM ALTER COLUMN no_semesters SET DEFAULT 6`?

Comment: You are not showing in your question how did you set the default value for that field.

Comment: Yes, I did. It also has the check constraint to see if the number is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Is your Db2-server running on i-series ?

Comment: Works fine for me in Db2 for i 7.2, given the statements you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in Db2 (for LUW) - the only thing to change is the table name needs to be in "" because of the /

```
CREATE TABLE "PREMIERD08/PGM" .....

INSERT INTO "PREMIERD08/PGM" (PGM_ID, PGM_NAME) 
VALUES('CPD', 'COMPUTER   PROGRAMMING')
```

Comment: PREMIERD08 is likely the schema (library) name in Db2 for i.

Comment: This is why it is always HELPFUL to specify the OS for Db2 questions